# "Languorous" versus "languid"

Tags: word-usage, connotation

"Languorous" and "languid" have similar meanings. Are there any subtle differences in usage, due to connotation perhaps, that make one more suitable than the other under certain circumstances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Languorous* has a more positive connotation, while *languid* conveys something more negative.

She lounged languorously by the pool. (positive and sexy)

It was a languid attempt at an answer. (negative and lazy)

*Languor* The state or feeling, often pleasant, of tiredness or inertia:

*Languid* (Of a person, manner, or gesture) displaying or having a disinclination for physical exertion or effort; slow and relaxed:

Source: Oxforddictionaries.com